# 8th Wall lighting

Tags: three.js, aframe, gltf, 8thwall-web

I made an AR Experience in 8th Wall and it's working pretty well.
The only thing is the lighting.
The model looks like this in the gltf viewer:

[image]

But when i load it into the AR experience the model looks like this:

[image]

I have added directional light that follows the model, added ambient ligh and hemisphere. I don't know how to solve this....

In gltf viewer, there is this option "punctualLights", with this the whole model is a lot brighter - is there a similar option for three js / aframe / 8th Wall?

Please help me, I Spended hours figuring this out

I have added directional light that follows the model, added ambient ligh and hemisphere. I don't know how to solve this....

In gltf viewer, there is this option "punctualLights", with this the whole model is a lot brighter - is there a similar option for three js / aframe / 8th Wall?

Answer (score 0):

The new 8th Wall cloud editor has an inbuilt model viewer that shows how light affects your model. Try Adjusting the intensity values to match your required texture result. The Gltf viewer has a black background hence it is sometimes difficult to verify if the textures are alpha blending in any way. I would recommend using 3D modeling software like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) to check material properties with respect to blending, metallicity, and roughness. In addition, you can also look into renderer property [physicallyCorrectLights](https://aframe.io/docs/1.5.0/components/renderer.html#properties_physicallycorrectlights), and play around with various scene lighting properties to fit your requirements.

[image]